# Machine Learning - Overfitting The Dataset On Purpose

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I learned **Machine Learning** recently, and I'm developing a **Tic Tac Toe** engine that predicts the best move in a given Tic Tac Toe position (or board state) as my first project. I used brute force to create all the possible positions for a **3 by 3** board (excluding completed and repeated games), and got **4520** different possible positions. Then I used **MinMax** to figure out the best move in each one of these positions. Now I want to fit a model to this data to achieve max accuracy. Something that I thought of is:

> Since I have all possible positions, why don't I train the model on the whole set (So there won't be a test set), and use a complicated `neural network` to overfit the data and get **100%** accuracy, then it will also be **100%** accurate in practical use since it **won't** encounter any new positions.

The thing is, I notice that people always refer to overfitting as a bad thing, **So my questions is: Is this a good practice? And why is it good or not?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overfitting is a problem when you want your model to generalize to new data. In your case there is no new data, so overfitting is not a problem.

But then, this is not what machine learning is usually used for, in most cases generalization is the whole point, this is why we go at lengths not to overfit.